# In javascript return member of an object by reference

Tags: javascript

I have a json object which is variable (with possibly infinite sub-structures):

```
var myObject={
    s1:{
        s2:'2',
        s3:'3'
    },
    s4:'4',
    s5:{
        s6:undefined
    },
    s7:'7'
};
```

I would like to find the first undefined member and to return it's reference,
to be able to modify it anytime (by event triggered functions)

```
function findFirstUndefined(obj){
    for (var key in obj){
        if (typeof(obj[key]) === 'object'){
            var recursion=findFirstUndefined(obj[key])
            if (recursion!==false){
                return recursion;
            }       
        }
        else if (obj[key]===undefined){
            return obj[key];
        }   
    }
    return false; 
}
```

But it doesn't return the reference of the member, but it's value:

```
var subObj=findFirstUndefined(myObject);
subObj="my updated cool var!!";
```

doesn't modify the object.

I found that a library like [JsonPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) could do the trick,
but it seems to me kind of heavy for such a simple task.

Wouldn't it exists an elegant way to do so? Thank's!

Comment: You've got an object, not JSON.

Comment: You could return a string `"s1"` and access it using `myObject[string]`. Not exactly pass by reference, but it's the best I can think of.

Comment: It looks like you return the undefined value: `else if (obj[key]===undefined){
            return obj[key];`

Comment: In order to change the value of an object property, you need to assign to a property reference, e.g. `obj.prop = 'new value';`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas you are right, I didn't double quoted everything, what I meant by json object is that i get it via a String and it doesn't contain any function

Comment: @Thor84no, i have no control over the variable name and there could be duplicates name

Comment: @user1843507 You can't have duplicated names, that would overwrite the value for the name you duplicated.

Comment: @Thor84no something like that: `{image1:{src:"..."},image2:{src:"..."}}` where knowing that the variable name is src is not sufficient

Comment: @user1843507 Knowing just 'src' would have never been sufficient in that case anyway as you would need to include the `image1`/`image2` portion as well to access it: `myObject['image1']['src']`.

Comment: @Thor84no yes exactly, I would have needed the path, and if you can think of a lightweight algorithm to do so, I am still very interested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JS doesn't do that.   You could instead return a function that will assign to the missing entry?

```
return function(v) { obj[key] = v; };
```

Comment: I like this solution very much.

Comment: Perfect!! I always forget to think of javascript as a functional language! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In JS you cannot control manually if the value is passed, or the reference.

And only objects are passed by reference.

So unfortunately you just cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

As you requested it in comments I'll post a way of getting/setting these objects based on a string path. It's up to you whether you think it's too complicated of course, but here it is.

```
function getValue(object, path) {
    value = object[path[0]];
    if (path.length > 1) {
        return getValue(value, path.slice(1, path.length))
    }
    return value;
}

function setValue(object, path, value) {
    if (path.length > 1) {
        setValue(object[path[0]], path.slice(1, path.length), value);
    }
    else {
        object[path[0]] = value
    }
}
```

You then use them like this: `getValue(myObject, ["s1", "s2"]);` / `setValue(myObject, ["s1", "s2"], value);`. I haven't had a chance to test the code, but the approach should hold.

Comment: Ah yes very nice answer, and I guess to find the path you would do something like that: -> another answer

Answer (score 0):

If you return `obj[key]` you are returning a value obviously but try to return an array of two values `[obj, key]` and you have a way of referencing that node. Or from your recursive function you can build up a multidimensional array with these kinds of pairs for later use.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findFirstUndefinedPath(obj){
    for (var key in obj){
        var path=[key];
        if (typeof(obj[key]) === 'object'){
            var subPath=findFirstUndefinedPath(obj[key]);
            if (subPath!==false){
                return path.concat(subPath);
            }       
        }
        else if (obj[key]===undefined){
            return path;
        }   
    }
    return false; 
}
```